# How to set values for date range in primeng

Tags: angular7, primeng, angular8

I am trying to set value during initializing form using primeng datepick calender but not working.I am working in angular 8.I have created custom datepicker component using primeng.I have given my code below.How to set date range value that?Anyone can have idea?please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<p-calendar  
    [(ngModel)]="datesRangeFilter"
    selectionMode="range" view="month" dateFormat="mm/yy" [readonlyInput]="true"
    [showIcon]="true">
</p-calendar>
```

app.component.ts:

```
datesRangeFilter:Date;

 ngOnInit(){

  let yesterday = ( d => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate()-1)) )(new Date);

  this.datesRangeFilter=yesterday +'-'+new Date;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign two different dates as an array, and it will be bind to the model.

component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
<p>
    Date Reset
</p>
<p-calendar formControlName="date" selectionMode="range" [readonlyInput]="true"></p-calendar>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
<button (click)="setCustomDateRange()">Set Custom Date Range</button>

</div>
```

Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl , FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  yearRange = '2000:2020';
  myGroup: any;
  rangeDates: Date[];
  constructor(){
    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
    date: new FormControl('')
  });
  }
  setCustomDateRange(){
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 10);
    this.myGroup.get('date').setValue([new Date(), date]);
  }
  reset(){
    console.log(this.myGroup.get('date').value)
    this.myGroup.get('date').setValue(null);
  }


}

[Working code][1]
```